# delete selected bones. Right click bug?

Tags: armature

While in edit mode of my armature, whenever I right click the model window it pops up "delete selected bones" instead of letting me right click on the bone I want.
This started happening mid way thru a project is is highly irritating yet I have no clue how to toggle it off.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have changed your key/mouse bindings. Have you tried resetting Blender to factory defaults?